# How to declare two classes with the same name in the project vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, xml-serialization, subclass

I'm starting in vb.net and I'm migrating my project vb6 to vb.net.
In my project I have in a file, a class named A, declared as follows:

```
Public Class A
.....
End Class
```

In another file I have to declare another class for local use, with the same class name already declared earlier in another file (Class A).
But both classes are different.

Then I tried the following:

```
Public Class Z
  Private _a As A
    Public Property a () As A
        Get
            Return _a
        Get End
        Set (ByVal value As A)
            _a = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class Z

Class A
......
End Class
```

Then I tried the following:

```
Public Class Z
  Private _a As A
    Public Property a () As A
        Get
            Return _a
        Get End
        Set (ByVal value As A)
            _a = value
        End Set
    End Property

Class A
......
End Class

End Class Z
```

The need is that when instantiating Z I get access local Class A
But I have the error message with saying:

Error 4 class 'A' and class 'A', declared in 'C: \ TFS \ SigaCom \ BsControl System 2014 \ BsSystem \ nfe \ A.vb' conflict in namespace 'BSSystemControl'. C: \ TFS \ SigaCom \ BsControl System 2014 \ BsSystem \ nfe \ impostoDevol.VB 12 7 BSControl

If I place the Class A statement within the class Z Scope, I got the following message:

Error 4 'A' is already declared the 'Public Property A The A' in this class. C: \ TFS \ SigaCom \ BsControl System 2014 \ BsSystem \ nfe \ impostoDevol.VB 12 11 BSControl

Comment: My first question would have to be... Is there some requirement for this naming scheme? Maybe you could describe in general terms what you are hoping to accomplish be having this requirement. It would help in providing a sensible answer with appropriate context. (As a note: VB is case insensitive, so your Property `a` is the same as your nested class `A`.)

Comment: Xml serialization will work off of the property names by default (type does not matter, so your classes can be named whatever you want) and/or by using the XmlElement(string) attribute on those properties.

Comment: Yes there is. scheme this appointment is to generate XML files through serialization that will be consumed by webservice.
I am using an XSD to create the class.
XSD have in the field:
**det.imposto.ipi** that has several fields.
That same XSD have the field:
**det.impostoDevol.ipi** having other fields (actually just one).

In this way I have the need for the same namesspace have two **ipi** classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is serialization, your class names do not matter in this regard. By default when serializing to XML the properties are what matter, the use of the property name can be overridden using the `XmlElement(string)` attribute. For instance, given the following structure:

```
Public Class Z
    Private _a As A2
    <XmlElement("A")> _
    Public Property a () As A2
        Get
            Return _a
        Get End
        Set (ByVal value As A2)
            _a = value
        End Set
    End Property

   Class A2
      '......
   End Class

End Class Z
```

Will serialize the to the same XML as:

```
Public Class Z
    Private _a As A2
    <XmlElement("A")> _
    Public Property ZZZZ () As A2
        Get
            Return _a
        Get End
        Set (ByVal value As A2)
            _a = value
        End Set
    End Property

   Class A2
      '......
   End Class

End Class Z
```

Which will also serialize to the same XML as:

```
Public Class Z
    Private _a As ZZZZ
    <XmlElement("A")> _
    Public Property CDEF () As ZZZZ
        Get
            Return _a
        Get End
        Set (ByVal value As ZZZZ)
            _a = value
        End Set
    End Property

   Class ZZZZ
      '......
   End Class

End Class Z
```

Answer (score 1):

The naming of your members does not follow naming conventions. Private objects should be named in camelCase, avoid using the "_" char at start, end, neither in the middle, public properties ans classes in TitleCase, also, names should be intuitive, a kind of short-name of a larger name.

Secondlly, I don't think you need a backing field at all for the sceneraio that you've exposed.

Anyways, to solve the problem that you are having just move each class with same classname to different namespaces with different names, this way you will avoid ambiguity, but that style of programming is incorrect.

If I understood good, this is what you intent to do?:

```
Public class TopLevelClass

Namespace name1

    Public Class Zclass

        Public Property A As Aclass

        Public Sub New()
            Me.A = New Aclass
        End Sub

        Public NotInheritable Class Aclass
            Public Sub New()
            End Sub
        End Class

    End Class

End Namespace

Namespace name2

    Public Class Zclass

        Public Property A As Aclass

        Public Sub New()
            Me.A = New Aclass
        End Sub

        Public NotInheritable Class Aclass
            Public Sub New()
            End Sub
        End Class

    End Class

End Namespace

End Class
```